# Script to find services & websites listening to port

Tags: windows, powershell, tcp, port

I have some some websites and services installed on the machine. They are assigned the port numbers. Now each time i would like to install the new server i have to check the ports and see if the existing port number is not used again.

I would like write a *i get to know that yes its possible to write a script which would help to get the port numbers used by services and websites*...but from `get-process` for example, there is no way to to get the port.

Can someone help me with this so that statistics for selected processes can be found?
Or there is even better way to deal with this issue?

Comment: I've tested the function mentioned in my answer and reported the results. It works fine for me. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be it's a silly answer, but why not:

```
$procstats = netstat -o
```

Yes I know, not really easy to manage that array of strings. Look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/02/04/how-to-query-for-netstat-info-using-powershell.aspx).

---

**Serious solution**

The most concrete way is using the win32 [`GetExtendedTcpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928%28VS.85%29.aspx) which allows you to retrieve the list of TCP endpoints along with the PID. The solution in [**this**](http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/netstat-for-powershell/) post provides a powershell binding to a c# netstat function which implements the win32 function. It looks pretty good.

After you have Port/PID/Address of the endpoint connection you can exploit [`System.Net.NetworkInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.aspx) classes to get information and statistics about the connection.

---

**After some test upon `get-netstat`**

It works like a charm. For example, the following one-line gets all TCP connections (remotely/locally) established on port 63775 along with the PID:

```
. .\get-nestat.ps1
$netstat = get-netstat | ? {($_.localport -eq 63775 -or $_.remoteport -eq 63775) -and $_.protocol -eq TCP -and $_.state -eq 'ESTABLISHED'} | select PID, PIDName, State, LocalIP, RemoteIP
```

You can now get the function file from [**my gists**](https://gist.github.com/958531).

Comment: A PowerShell function that appends all the info into a single string?  My eyes are bleeding...

Comment: yes, netstat solution is little rude :) Edited the answer with a more serious solution.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a nice solution [here](http://halr9000.com/article/599) also working on `Netstat`.

```
netstat -a -n -o
```

Answer (score 1):

While I know that PowerShell is perfectly capable of running `netstat` and capturing the output, it's still text parsing and not object oriented as PowerShell is wont to be.  So, I submit my PowerShell replication of `netstat -aon` with the addition of adding Service information.  What it doesn't do is identify the specific *website* listening port as specified by the original question.  To me, that would be more of an IIS script rather than a general networking script.  Again, many thanks to [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.GetExtendedTcpTable) (to where I also posted this code).

```
$TypeDefinition=@"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

// https://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366073.aspx
namespace IPHelper {

    // https://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366913.aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID {
        public uint state;
        public uint localAddr;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public byte[] localPort;
        public uint remoteAddr;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public byte[] remotePort;
        public uint owningPid;
    }

    // https://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366921.aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID {
        public uint dwNumEntries;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 1)]
        public MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[] table;
     }

    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366896
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        public byte[] localAddr;
        public uint localScopeId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public byte[] localPort;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        public byte[] remoteAddr;
        public uint remoteScopeId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public byte[] remotePort;
        public uint state;
        public uint owningPid;
    }

    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366905
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MIB_TCP6TABLE_OWNER_PID {
       public uint dwNumEntries;
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 1)]
       public MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID[] table;
    }

    // https://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366386.aspx
    public enum TCP_TABLE_CLASS {
        TCP_TABLE_BASIC_LISTENER,
        TCP_TABLE_BASIC_CONNECTIONS,
        TCP_TABLE_BASIC_ALL,
        TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_LISTENER,
        TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS,
        TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL,
        TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_LISTENER,
        TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_CONNECTIONS,
        TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_ALL
    }

    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366896.aspx
    public enum MIB_TCP_STATE {
        MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSED,
        MIB_TCP_STATE_LISTEN,
        MIB_TCP_STATE_SYN_SENT,
        MIB_TCP_STATE_SYN_RCVD,
        MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB,
        MIB_TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT1,
        MIB_TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT2,
        MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSE_WAIT,
        MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSING,
        MIB_TCP_STATE_LAST_ACK,
        MIB_TCP_STATE_TIME_WAIT,
        MIB_TCP_STATE_DELETE_TCB
    }

    public static class IPHelperAPI {
        [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint GetExtendedTcpTable(
            IntPtr tcpTable,
            ref int tcpTableLength,
            bool sort,
            int ipVersion,
            TCP_TABLE_CLASS tcpTableType,
            int reserved=0);
    }

    public class IPHelperWrapper : IDisposable {

        public const int AF_INET = 2;    // IP_v4 = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork
        public const int AF_INET6 = 23;  // IP_v6 = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6

        // Creates a new wrapper for the local machine
        public IPHelperWrapper() { }

        // Disposes of this wrapper
        public void Dispose() { GC.SuppressFinalize(this); }

        public List<MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID> GetAllTCPv4Connections() {
            return GetTCPConnections<MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID, MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID>(AF_INET);
        }

        public List<MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID> GetAllTCPv6Connections() {
            return GetTCPConnections<MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID, MIB_TCP6TABLE_OWNER_PID>(AF_INET6);
        }

        public List<IPR> GetTCPConnections<IPR, IPT>(int ipVersion) { //IPR = Row Type, IPT = Table Type

            IPR[] tableRows;
            int buffSize = 0;
            var dwNumEntriesField = typeof(IPT).GetField("dwNumEntries");

            // how much memory do we need?
            uint ret = IPHelperAPI.GetExtendedTcpTable(IntPtr.Zero, ref buffSize, true, ipVersion, TCP_TABLE_CLASS.TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL);
            IntPtr tcpTablePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffSize);

            try {
                ret = IPHelperAPI.GetExtendedTcpTable(tcpTablePtr, ref buffSize, true, ipVersion, TCP_TABLE_CLASS.TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL);
                if (ret != 0) return new List<IPR>();

                // get the number of entries in the table
                IPT table = (IPT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tcpTablePtr, typeof(IPT));
                int rowStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IPR));
                uint numEntries = (uint)dwNumEntriesField.GetValue(table);

                // buffer we will be returning
                tableRows = new IPR[numEntries];

                IntPtr rowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)tcpTablePtr + 4);
                for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
                    IPR tcpRow = (IPR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(rowPtr, typeof(IPR));
                    tableRows[i] = tcpRow;
                    rowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)rowPtr + rowStructSize);   // next entry
                }
            }
            finally {
                // Free the Memory
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tcpTablePtr);
            }
            return tableRows != null ? tableRows.ToList() : new List<IPR>();
        }

        // Occurs on destruction of the Wrapper
        ~IPHelperWrapper() { Dispose(); }

    } // wrapper class
} // namespace
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $TypeDefinition -PassThru | Out-Null

function NetStat {

  $x=New-Object IPHelper.IPHelperWrapper
  $y=$x.GetAllTCPv4Connections()
  $services=Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class "Win32_Service"
  $StateList=@("UNKNOWN","CLOSED","LISTEN","SYN-SENT","SYN-RECEIVED","ESTABLISHED","FIN-WAIT-1","FIN-WAIT-2","CLOSE-WAIT","CLOSING","LAST-ACK","TIME-WAIT","DELETE-TCB")
  $output=@()
  for ($i=0; $i -lt $y.Count; $i++) {
    $objOutput=New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    Add-Member -InputObject $objOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LocalAddress" -Value ([System.Net.IPAddress]::new($y[$i].localAddr).IPAddressToString)
    Add-Member -InputObject $objOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "RemoteAddress" -Value ([System.Net.IPAddress]::new($y[$i].remoteAddr).IPAddressToString)
    Add-Member -InputObject $objOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LocalPort" -Value ($y[$i].localPort[1]+($y[$i].localPort[0]*0x100)+($y[$i].localPort[3]*0x1000)+($y[$i].localPort[2]*0x10000))
    Add-Member -InputObject $objOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "RemotePort" -Value ($y[$i].remotePort[1]+($y[$i].remotePort[0]*0x100)+($y[$i].remotePort[3]*0x1000)+($y[$i].remotePort[2]*0x10000))
    Add-Member -InputObject $objOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PID" -Value $y[$i].owningPid
    Add-Member -InputObject $objOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ProcessName" -Value ((Get-Process -Id $y[$i].owningPid).ProcessName)
    Add-Member -InputObject $objOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "StateValue" -Value $y[$i].state
    Add-Member -InputObject $objOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "State" -Value $StateList[$y[$i].state]
    $boolNoService=$true
    for ($j=0; $j -lt $services.Count; $j++) {
      if ($services[$j].ProcessId -eq $y[$i].owningPid) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $objOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServiceName" -Value $services[$j].Caption
        $boolNoService=$false
        break;
      }
    }
    if ($boolNoService) { Add-Member -InputObject $objOutput -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServiceName" -Value $null }
    $output+=$objOutput
  }
  $output
}

NetStat
```